# MySQL query not showing all results in table. INNER JOIN conflict

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a list of mentors. Some of the mentors have ratings and some don't. Currently, my query gathers the mentors' basic information and also their rating info. Because the query is gathering rating info, mentors without ratings aren't being shown in the table, while only the mentors with ratings are. Is there a way around this?

Here's my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT users.id, users.firstName, users.lastName, users.username, users.gender, users.avatar, mentor.industry, mentor.city, mentor.price, mentor.language, users.country, mentor.mentor_enabled, AVG(rating.rate) AS average, COUNT(rate) AS count FROM users INNER JOIN mentor ON users.id = mentor.id INNER JOIN rating ON mentor.id = rating.owner WHERE mentor.mentor_enabled='1' GROUP BY users.id, users.username ORDER BY RAND()";
$res = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());               
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        //NAMING VARIABLES
    }
 } else{
  echo "no data";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `left outer join` instead of `inner join` to get all the rows, e.g.:

```
SELECT users.id, users.firstName, users.lastName, users.username, users.gender, users.avatar, mentor.industry, mentor.city, mentor.price, mentor.language, users.country, mentor.mentor_enabled, AVG(rating.rate) AS average, COUNT(rate) AS count 
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN mentor ON users.id = mentor.id 
INNER JOIN rating ON mentor.id = rating.owner 
WHERE mentor.mentor_enabled='1' 
GROUP BY users.id, users.username 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: You are simply AMAZING! I've been trying and trying for days now and the left outer join saved my mind! Thank you so much! This was a great learning experience and I want to research the joins more! Thank you! I'll mark you answer as soon as I can! :D :D

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x WHERE x.n ...` is identical to `INNER JOIN x...`